# 2D array that player can move around

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am confused on how to print the location of the player in this array and have it update every time an input is plugged in for the direction it is moving? Currently I only get the - symbol in a 10 by 10 pattern but would like (0,0) to be an X where the player starts.

```
private final static int SIZEX = 10; // Board size
private final static int SIZEY = 10; // Board size

    int[][] gameboard = new int[SIZEX][SIZEY];


    for(int i=0; i<gameboard.length; i++) 
        {          
            for(int j=0; j<gameboard.length; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print("-");

            }
            System.out.println("");         
        }
```

Comment: Instread of just printing '-' you could print the content of the gameboard. Of course right now would contain garbages so you need to initialize it's values. You could assigned as 0 the empty space and as an 1 the place where the user is ( having two variables like userXPos and userYPos would be nice ). after you initialize your array you would display it's content depending of what contains in each cell if you find 0 just print a '-' otherwise 'X'

Comment: Of course before you update the users moment you will need to empty his previous location by setting gameboard[playerXPos][[playerYPos] = 0; after that you will take his new cords (x,y) and will update the gameboard[playerXPos][[playerYPos] = 1 with the updated coordinates.

Comment: How would i print the x at the starting position though?

Comment: Depending of what you mean starting position. First create two variables as a said playerXPos and playerYPos and then set to them some default values between 0-9. If for example you want the user to start at location 5,5 just go to the gameboard at gameboard[playerXPos][[playerYPos] and set it's content to 1 so you know that the player is there. After that draw the gameboard again and where you find the 1 you will print 'X"

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement (or ternary operator) in your inner loop to print `X` if i and j match the x and y coordinate of the player

Answer (score 0):

You could add a KeyListener to your games Component and set the x and y if the input matches the one required to move the player arround and print the position once the key is released.

To really answer your question we would need some sort of fields you have that hold the current players position